# Export matrix to Microsoft Access. Error using database/insert

Tags: database, matlab, ms-access, matrix, export

**Hello!** 
Below is the code for the following task:

- matrix "Q" with a dimension of 3*2 was obtained using a matrix of cells "A";
- then the matrix "Q" is exported to Microsoft Access with the same dimension (3 rows, 2 columns).

**(!)** The **difficulty** is that only the first row of the matrix is written to Microsoft Access (of the three available) and then an error message is displayed:

- Error using database/insert (line 213) General error
- Error in test_matlab (line 22) insert(conn, 'Rtu', colnames, Q);

**(?)** Tell me, please, how is it necessary to add / correct the code in order to record all three rows of the matrix in Microsoft Access?

```
Q=[];
A={1, [3 5 8]} % array of cells

for j=1:2 % matrix column index
for i=1:3 % matrix row index
if j==1
Q(i,j)=A{1,j};
else 
Q(i,j)=A{1,j}(1,i);
end
end
end

Q

conn = database('QWERT', '', '');
colnames = {'u1', 'u2'};

insert(conn, 'Rtu', colnames, Q);
close(conn);
```

- I use matlab version R2014b.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use matlab, but normal programming practice would suggest to put the insert into your outer for loop:
would this work?

```
Q=[];
A={1, [3 5 8]} % array of cells
conn = database('QWERT', '', '');
colnames = {'u1', 'u2'};

for j=1:2 % matrix column index
  for i=1:3 % matrix row index
    if j==1
      Q(i,j)=A{1,j};
    else 
      Q(i,j)=A{1,j}(1,i);
    end
  end
  insert(conn, 'Rtu', colnames, Q);
end

Q

close(conn);
```

or put another for loop just around the insert...

Comment: Unfortunately, the use of the cycle did not help.
As it turned out, the code was correct. 
The problem was in the settings of Microsoft Access. 
It was necessary to specify in the settings of Microsoft Access "Сoncordance of Element are allowed". Before this was specified in the settings "Сoncordance of Element are not allowed".
In result, the program began to work correctly after changing the settings. 
Thank you for the answer, Trevor! After working with the cycles, I thought about the settings. I corrected and the program works correctly.